# Speed up text mining (and for loop) in R

Tags: r, for-loop, text, frequency, text-mining

I'm text-mining thousands of documents (basically doing frequency count) and wondering is there any other ways to speed up the following process? Currently it takes more than 10 hours to run the whole analysis. Thank you (from an R beginner).

```
sessionInfo() 
#R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

library(bitops)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
library(tm)

setwd("F:/testing_folder")
path = "F:/testing_folder" 

file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".txt") 
filename <- vector()
totalword <- vector()

system.time(
  for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
    text.v <- scan(file.names[i], what="character", sep="\n",encoding = "UTF-8") 
    report.v <- paste(text.v, collapse=" " ) 

    #Count total number of words
    words.l <- strsplit(report.v, "\\W") 
    word.v <- unlist(words.l) 
    not.blanks.v <- which(word.v!="") 
    word.v <- word.v[not.blanks.v] 
    totalword <- append(totalword,length(word.v)) 

    filename <- append(filename,print(file.names[i])) 
    x <- data.frame(filename,totalword)  
    write.csv(x, file= "results.csv") #export results
  }
)
```

Comment: Instead of `filename <- vector(); totalword <- vector()` you should preallocate them to the right size upfront. This will give you a noticeable speed up. Also, don't run `write.csv` in each iteration of the loop - it will simplify overwrite the results in every run which takes time and doesn't make much sense

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure I fully understand what you meant. Can you be more specific, say, if I have 10,300 documents in total, what should I do?

Comment: You problem is not reproducible so it's hard to know exactly what you're doing. What I said were general comments that you shouldn't grow an object in a loop (instead you should preallocate it, look at `?vector`) and that you are just overwriting the results of the csv file in each loop operation, hence you should simply remove it from the loop and write it afterwards

Comment: I see, thank you, so could you give me some hints on how to modify the code, especially where should I place this one `write.csv(x, file= "results.csv")`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you get from the following?

```
Rprof("profile1.out", line.profiling=TRUE)
source("http://pastebin.com/raw/kFGCse5s")
Rprof(NULL)
proftable("profile1.out", lines=10)
```

Comment: I tested my code using a random 500 files (original sample is way too large and takes too much time to run through) here is the output from `summaryRprof("profile1.out")` http://pastebin.com/WnsTUYgr

Comment: What do you mean "run it on 1"?

Comment: Profiling your code shows you which line(s) are taking most time, which can help you make it quicker.  You should only need to run the loop once (i.e. on a single file) to profile it..